# Gradle very slow with play-services:8.4.0

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-play-services

I have problem,I use  play-services:8.4.0 in my project and when compile my project gradle it's very very slow!!

It takes 5 - 9 minutes in compile the project.

why?

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid from compiling whole play-services. You may only use the necessary one. For example if you just want to use play-services for the ads,

instead of typing:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

just type this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
```

If you don't know which one you need you may check this [Selectively compiling APIs into your executable](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

I hope it helps!